# How to achieve string formatting in jquery?

Tags: jquery, string-formatting

I want to format a string before assigning it to a label's text property in jquery. I want something as follows (code is in C#),

```
string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", m.hire_dt);
```

I am trying to format a date and other strings too. How could i achieve that?

Comment: jQuery API has virtually no string methods other than $.trim() since no real need to wrap native javascript methods

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Do you just want to format a date, or do you want to try to format other things too?

Comment: I am trying to format a date and other strings too. How could i achieve that?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/463065) question out, just use javascript for this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to format a date string, you can try [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/637369) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript). It's basically suggests that you need to concatenate the different date components.

If you are using jquery UI and you need the built-in datetime picker, there's a [`formatDate`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) function wherein you can specify which format you prefer.

For general date manipulation, it is best to use [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/).